# Unable to Install lxml on Windows 7

Tags: python, xml, pip, lxml

I know there have been many questions on how to install lxml, and I have followed all the steps I have found (which I have detailed below). However, given what I have done, I am ultimately unable to install the packages and have been stuck on it for quite some time.

**Option 1:** installing lxml with pip

As many of the straightforward answers, I have tried to install lxml by doing `pip install lxml`, but I am getting the error in the below screenshot. I'm not quite sure what it means, but I can only assume that it's a connection being refused by my company (I am able to install it on a personal VM that I have spun up at home)

[image]

**Option 2:** installing lxml from source

I have followed the instructions [here](https://lxml.de/2.3/build.html) on how to build `lxml` from the source, but I am getting another error asking me that I need to download Visual C++. I did so from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe.), but I'm not able to actually execute the build tools (I think) due to my company restrictions (it is being blocked).

Is there any other way that I can install `lxml` given what I've done above? If these are the only ways, what do I need to say to my company tech administrators to allow me to the download the package (especially in the first option)?

Comment: lxml is a library that internaly is a binding to libxml2 c library. So before you can install lxml you need to have libxml2 lib. You can also use unofficial lib from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml. I got this link from this page: https://lxml.de/installation.html#source-builds-on-ms-windows. Sometimes using 
cygwin or mingw will be much simpler

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 'Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages', they already provide a prebuild [lxml](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) version for Python3.8.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried doing that but I'm getting an error message saying "lxml-4.4.1-pp372-pp372-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform"? Do you know what that means why that is? I'm using python 3.7.4

Comment: 32/64bit issue ?!

Comment: Hmm perhaps. I'll give the other version a try.

Comment: Indeed it was a 32/64 bit issue!

Answer (score 1):

There's no available lxml version for python3.8 (which you're using)

You could use setup py to install it:

```
git clone https://github.com/lxml/lxml.git lxml
cd lxml
python3.8 setup.py install
```

Alternatively try to specify the version, e.g.

```
pip install lxml==4.4.1
```

Comment: There are no files for python 3.8 for lxml3.8

Comment: Thanks! I've tried doing the same with python 2.7.5 but the same thing happens. I'll give your solutions a try but which python version should i be using in that case?

Comment: 3.7 seems a better choice.